# Finding closest power of 2 for any float at compile time

Tags: c

I need to scale all floats to `[-1,1]` range by dividing with **closest higher** power of 2. The code needs to be Q0.31 fixed-point, so no floats.

For example, 10.75 would be divided by 16, 20.91 by 32, 1000.17 by 1024, etc, all the way to 2^31.

I'd need the scaling to be done at compilation time.

For example:

```
#define PARAMETER1 10.0f // this could be changed in various builds
#define PARAMETER1_SCALE ( CALC_SCALE(PARAMETER1) )

#define float_to_fixed(x) ( (int)( (float)(x)*(float)0x80000000 ) )

int main()
{
    int par1 = float_to_fixed( PARAMETER1/PARAMETER1_SCALE );

    // use par1 here
    // ...
    // then descale using PARAMETER1_SCALE again      
}
```

Is there a C macro `CALC_SCALE` which would calculate this?

Comment: C or C++? Macro or function or any?

Comment: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogFloat

Comment: Why a macro (and not a function)? (Also remove either the C or the C++ tag)

Comment: I'm sorry, that's simply mathematics, just think about it once again..

Comment: `pow(2, ceil(log2(10.75)))` maybe?

Comment: Maybe OP wants to look at the IEEE representation and manipulate the raw DWORD (OP mentioned float, not sure if that was `float` or the English term)???

Comment: @franji1 Since there is not mandate in C++ that floats be IEEE that would bind the OP to specific implementations that do.

Comment: Please, a Macro if possible.

Comment: `frexp` in the math library will return the result you want, but it's not a macro (the return value is not the exponent, it's the value that you're trying to calculate).

Comment: Added more info to the questions, please check it.

Comment: why do you want a macro?

Comment: Can it be done like the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does it:

```
#define CALC_SCALE ( x > 16 ? 32 : x > 8 ? 16 : x > 4 ? 8 : x > 2 ? 4 : x > 1 ? 2 : 1 )
```

At compile time:

```
int x = CALC_SCALE( 13 );
```

is compiled to:

```
int x = 16;
```

This can easily be changed to support floats.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
#include <math.h>

#define collapse(value) (value < 0 ? value / pow(2, ceil(log2(value * -1))) : value / pow(2, ceil(log2(value)))) 

int main() {
    cout << collapse(10.75) << endl;
    cout << collapse(20.91) << endl;
    cout << collapse(-1) << endl;
    cout << collapse(-2.5) << endl;
    cout << collapse(5.7) << endl;
}
```

Output is:

```
0.671875
0.653438
-1
-0.625
0.7125
```